# How do we improve the question rate?

Tags: discussion

To avoid a quick shut down like the previous beta we should really maintain an high question rate. After a first day full of question, the rate dropped significantly.

I personally think we should:

- Re-ask old questions (searching for new answer) from the previous beta as [discussed here.](https://computergraphics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44/questions-from-the-previous-private-beta)
- Ask questions that we think interesting even though we already know an answer. At this early stage I think is important to build a good set of interesting questions as "database" for the future. If the answer we already knew asking the question is more complete that the ones received, then we can answer our own questions.
- Ask questions from [the definition stage](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/74985?phase=definition) of this board if considered appropriate.

What do you think?

Comment: I'm very happy to see questions from the definition stage *provided they are fleshed out into full questions*. The definition stage only had question *titles*, which are not sufficient alone.

Comment: I really like your second suggestion too - it could include "I wish I'd known when I started" questions, as long as they are reasonably advanced.

Comment: Not only the number of questions, but the number of visits also seems important, and did not look enough currently (or is it only an indicator for the public beta? I don't remember if we reached it last time).

Comment: I didn't realise you guys were struggling to find questions. I find everything about CG programming so fascinating. It's like the smarter (not really, but more mathematically reliant) side of programming. I will try ask some decent questions when I can.

Answer (score 3):

Nathan Reed links to [changes to Stack Exchange beta policy](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/257614/graduation-site-closure-and-a-clearer-outlook-on-the-health-of-se-sites).

While this is fantastic news, I got the impression that this applied to public beta sites, and that private beta sites would still need to prove themselves quickly. I've just read that post again and I can't see any suggestion that private beta sites would share this protection. It would be wonderful to hear that we could have longer to build up a base of questions, but unless that's made clear I'm going to assume we need to act quickly. If a Stack Exchange employee happens to read this it would be great to get confirmation either way about whether this applies to private beta sites.

---

## Breadth before quantity

I don't think number of questions is necessarily important during private beta, but the scope needs to be defined very clearly if we are to survive, and that requires a *breadth* of questions. Having a wide variety of questions will also require a reasonably large number of questions, but it is important to focus on the breadth rather than the number. Hundreds of questions without sufficient variation to explore the scope are unlikely to get us to public beta.

I'd like to see lots of different questions that come up in lots of different computer graphics settings, and questions that are on the border of the scope to trigger lots of discussion on meta.

Answer (score 1):

I agree it would be good to work on our question rate, but just wanted to let everyone know that there were some [changes to StackExchange beta policy](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/257614/graduation-site-closure-and-a-clearer-outlook-on-the-health-of-se-sites) since last year, and **a slow question rate is no longer grounds (on its own) for closing a site**.

We might not "graduate" from beta to a full-fledged site until our question rate reaches a steady 10 per day, but according to the policy, we aren't in danger of being shut down—unless our moderators quit and the site fills up with spam, or something.